# Why Active Record storing integer value in the format of BigDecimal notation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am a newbie. observe following screen shots, I have a model `Books` with following columns.

```
class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   create_table :books do |t|
     t.string :title
     t.text :author
     t.integer :price
     t.integer :book_id
    end
 end
end
```

Later I add a column to existing table like following

```
class AddBookIdToBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :books, :book_id, :integer
  end
end
```

I add a record into table `Book` using `form helpers`. But it is storing `book_id` value in the format of `BigDecimal` notation instead of `integer`.

Why it is storing like that?? Thanks in advance.

observe following screen shot here

```
2.2.2 :023 > Book.all
Book Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Book id: 7, title: "Wings Of Fire",   author: "kalam's", price: 120, created_at: "2015-12-09 09:57:10", updated_at: "2015-12-09 09:57:10", book_id: #<BigDecimal:4f39ea0,'0.1001E4',9(27)>>]>
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  (postgres, mysql etc)

Comment: sqlite db @Max Williams

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but shouldn't price be a float rather than an int?  What if the book is $7.99?

Comment: What is the result of going into the sqllite console for this database and typing `.schema books`?

Comment: <code> ' sqlite> .schema books
CREATE TABLE "books" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "title" varchar, "author" text, "price" integer, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL, "book_id" integer);'<code> @Max Williams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add an id for your model. Rails does it for you. When you add a column called "model"_id, Rails infers that it will be a reference to other table (association).

Comment: Ohh okay.thank you for reply. but my question is why it is storing 'integer' value in 'BigDecimal' format?? @Bruno Paulino

Comment: That is weird @NarasimhaReddy. Are you sure you have ran the migration with t.integer? because it seems that you are using t.decimal instead. try to rollback your db and migrate again without this book_id column and see what happens.

Comment: I am happy you solved :D. Can you post your solution @NarasimhaReddy?